# Rails controller checking for information already in the table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

How does one check to see if some data already exists in one of the tables in the controller?
So for example lets say in the create action you want to prevent the following from happening:
@equip = @petowner.equips.new(params[:equip])
this variable contains data that already exists in the equips table.
I would like to prevent the data of a given inventory from being applied a second time.

```
while @intable == 1, @intable not end of file, @intable++
if @equip.inventory_id == @intable.inventory_id
   # Render a failure message that returns back to new saying that this data already has been applied to a a given pet.
end
```

If it succeds and doesn't find the information then it should continue on forward.
In Equips controller is where I want the check to occur, but don't know how to accomplish it is Rails 3.2.13

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`.exists?()`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/exists?/class) function

```
if Model.exists?(id) then
    #do stuff
end
```

You might want to also put some validations in the model itself, such as [`validates uniqueness`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness):

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :email, uniqueness: true
end
```

Comment: This sounds like something I could try, but could you tell me how the exists? works? I have uniqueness fields already in place in the models to try tying a petowner and inventory together validates :pet_owner, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: inventory_id}